# How to make a general FPS counter?

Tags: java, swing, frame-rate

I have searched this questions and all I get the normal FPS counter which you put in your game loop.
but what I want to do is a general FPS counter which runs alongside any game and displays its FPS.
my Idea was to make a transparent `JFrame` with on big `JLabel` and add them at any corner of the screen. then override the paint method and whenever it's called that means that a new frame was painted and calculate the frequency of the frame repaintings and display it in the `JLabel`.
 but it doesn't seem to work as the paint methods is called on or two times then it isn't called again.

Comment: post a sample of code you have tried

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paint method is only getting called when it needs to. So if there isnt any update on the JFrame it wont get called. Thats why it stops after executing two or so times.
So your aproach is right if you only want to know how many times the JFrame gets painted and you have access to the codebase itself. But since you want to cap the fps of another frame without touching the code of the frame itself its impossible to add a fps counter for this scenario. But you could use JNI to achieve this.

Comment: I don't exactly get you. but I want that the program will run and then when I run  a game that Is completely separate from the FPS program it will calculate its FPS.

Comment: The FPS is the rate of frames per second. Its bound to the frame and can't be seperated from the program. You need to calculate it internaly if youre doing something like a game. So in your repaint method you should calculate your FPS. But because your screen most likely doesnt have things that get changed the JPanel wont repaint until you change something in the JPanel.

Comment: so how programs like [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/) works

Comment: FRAPS doesnt show the fps of the game. It shows the fps of the recording. So again you cant get the fps of other frames.